# Set 4 pictures in a row instead of 2 pictures

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following code successfully runs without an error, but it displays only two pictures in a row, I need 4 pictures in a row, and other pictures are not needed, only need 4 pictures. I think removing the pictures from `li` tags will remove excess pictures, but how to set 4 pictures in a row instead of two pictures? Thanks.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>


       <script>
       /* Modernizr 2.6.2 (Custom Build) | MIT & BSD
 * Build: http://modernizr.com/download/#-touch-shiv-cssclasses-teststyles-prefixes-load
 */
;window.Modernizr=function(a,b,c){function w(a){j.cssText=a}function x(a,b){return w(m.join(a+";")+(b||""))}function y(a,b){return typeof a===b}function z(a,b){return!!~(""+a).indexOf(b)}function A(a,b,d){for(var e in a){var f=b[a[e]];if(f!==c)return d===!1?a[e]:y(f,"function")?f.bind(d||b):f}return!1}var d="2.6.2",e={},f=!0,g=b.documentElement,h="modernizr",i=b.createElement(h),j=i.style,k,l={}.toString,m=" -webkit- -moz- -o- -ms- ".split(" "),n={},o={},p={},q=[],r=q.slice,s,t=function(a,c,d,e){var f,i,j,k,l=b.createElement("div"),m=b.body,n=m||b.createElement("body");if(parseInt(d,10))while(d--)j=b.createElement("div"),j.id=e?e[d]:h+(d+1),l.appendChild(j);return f=["&#173;",'<style id="s',h,'">',a,"</style>"].join(""),l.id=h,(m?l:n).innerHTML+=f,n.appendChild(l),m||(n.style.background="",n.style.overflow="hidden",k=g.style.overflow,g.style.overflow="hidden",g.appendChild(n)),i=c(l,a),m?l.parentNode.removeChild(l):(n.parentNode.removeChild(n),g.style.overflow=k),!!i},u={}.hasOwnProperty,v;!y(u,"undefined")&&!y(u.call,"undefined")?v=function(a,b){return u.call(a,b)}:v=function(a,b){return b in a&&y(a.constructor.prototype[b],"undefined")},Function.prototype.bind||(Function.prototype.bind=function(b){var c=this;if(typeof c!="function")throw new TypeError;var d=r.call(arguments,1),e=function(){if(this instanceof e){var a=function(){};a.prototype=c.prototype;var f=new a,g=c.apply(f,d.concat(r.call(arguments)));return Object(g)===g?g:f}return c.apply(b,d.concat(r.call(arguments)))};return e}),n.touch=function(){var c;return"ontouchstart"in a||a.DocumentTouch&&b instanceof DocumentTouch?c=!0:t(["@media (",m.join("touch-enabled),("),h,")","{#modernizr{top:9px;position:absolute}}"].join(""),function(a){c=a.offsetTop===9}),c};for(var B in n)v(n,B)&&(s=B.toLowerCase(),e[s]=n[B](),q.push((e[s]?"":"no-")+s));return e.addTest=function(a,b){if(typeof a=="object")for(var d in a)v(a,d)&&e.addTest(d,a[d]);else{a=a.toLowerCase();if(e[a]!==c)return e;b=typeof b=="function"?b():b,typeof f!="undefined"&&f&&(g.className+=" "+(b?"":"no-")+a),e[a]=b}return e},w(""),i=k=null,function(a,b){function k(a,b){var c=a.createElement("p"),d=a.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]||a.documentElement;return c.innerHTML="x<style>"+b+"</style>",d.insertBefore(c.lastChild,d.firstChild)}function l(){var a=r.elements;return typeof a=="string"?a.split(" "):a}function m(a){var b=i[a[g]];return b||(b={},h++,a[g]=h,i[h]=b),b}function n(a,c,f){c||(c=b);if(j)return c.createElement(a);f||(f=m(c));var g;return f.cache[a]?g=f.cache[a].cloneNode():e.test(a)?g=(f.cache[a]=f.createElem(a)).cloneNode():g=f.createElem(a),g.canHaveChildren&&!d.test(a)?f.frag.appendChild(g):g}function o(a,c){a||(a=b);if(j)return a.createDocumentFragment();c=c||m(a);var d=c.frag.cloneNode(),e=0,f=l(),g=f.length;for(;e<g;e++)d.createElement(f[e]);return d}function p(a,b){b.cache||(b.cache={},b.createElem=a.createElement,b.createFrag=a.createDocumentFragment,b.frag=b.createFrag()),a.createElement=function(c){return r.shivMethods?n(c,a,b):b.createElem(c)},a.createDocumentFragment=Function("h,f","return function(){var n=f.cloneNode(),c=n.createElement;h.shivMethods&&("+l().join().replace(/\w+/g,function(a){return b.createElem(a),b.frag.createElement(a),'c("'+a+'")'})+");return n}")(r,b.frag)}function q(a){a||(a=b);var c=m(a);return r.shivCSS&&!f&&!c.hasCSS&&(c.hasCSS=!!k(a,"article,aside,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section{display:block}mark{background:#FF0;color:#000}")),j||p(a,c),a}var c=a.html5||{},d=/^<|^(?:button|map|select|textarea|object|iframe|option|optgroup)$/i,e=/^(?:a|b|code|div|fieldset|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|i|label|li|ol|p|q|span|strong|style|table|tbody|td|th|tr|ul)$/i,f,g="_html5shiv",h=0,i={},j;(function(){try{var a=b.createElement("a");a.innerHTML="<xyz></xyz>",f="hidden"in a,j=a.childNodes.length==1||function(){b.createElement("a");var a=b.createDocumentFragment();return typeof a.cloneNode=="undefined"||typeof a.createDocumentFragment=="undefined"||typeof a.createElement=="undefined"}()}catch(c){f=!0,j=!0}})();var r={elements:c.elements||"abbr article aside audio bdi canvas data datalist details figcaption figure footer header hgroup mark meter nav output progress section summary time video",shivCSS:c.shivCSS!==!1,supportsUnknownElements:j,shivMethods:c.shivMethods!==!1,type:"default",shivDocument:q,createElement:n,createDocumentFragment:o};a.html5=r,q(b)}(this,b),e._version=d,e._prefixes=m,e.testStyles=t,g.className=g.className.replace(/(^|\s)no-js(\s|$)/,"$1$2")+(f?" js "+q.join(" "):""),e}(this,this.document),function(a,b,c){function d(a){return"[object Function]"==o.call(a)}function e(a){return"string"==typeof a}function f(){}function g(a){return!a||"loaded"==a||"complete"==a||"uninitialized"==a}function h(){var a=p.shift();q=1,a?a.t?m(function(){("c"==a.t?B.injectCss:B.injectJs)(a.s,0,a.a,a.x,a.e,1)},0):(a(),h()):q=0}function i(a,c,d,e,f,i,j){function k(b){if(!o&&g(l.readyState)&&(u.r=o=1,!q&&h(),l.onload=l.onreadystatechange=null,b)){"img"!=a&&m(function(){t.removeChild(l)},50);for(var d in y[c])y[c].hasOwnProperty(d)&&y[c][d].onload()}}var j=j||B.errorTimeout,l=b.createElement(a),o=0,r=0,u={t:d,s:c,e:f,a:i,x:j};1===y[c]&&(r=1,y[c]=[]),"object"==a?l.data=c:(l.src=c,l.type=a),l.width=l.height="0",l.onerror=l.onload=l.onreadystatechange=function(){k.call(this,r)},p.splice(e,0,u),"img"!=a&&(r||2===y[c]?(t.insertBefore(l,s?null:n),m(k,j)):y[c].push(l))}function j(a,b,c,d,f){return q=0,b=b||"j",e(a)?i("c"==b?v:u,a,b,this.i++,c,d,f):(p.splice(this.i++,0,a),1==p.length&&h()),this}function k(){var a=B;return a.loader={load:j,i:0},a}var l=b.documentElement,m=a.setTimeout,n=b.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],o={}.toString,p=[],q=0,r="MozAppearance"in l.style,s=r&&!!b.createRange().compareNode,t=s?l:n.parentNode,l=a.opera&&"[object Opera]"==o.call(a.opera),l=!!b.attachEvent&&!l,u=r?"object":l?"script":"img",v=l?"script":u,w=Array.isArray||function(a){return"[object Array]"==o.call(a)},x=[],y={},z={timeout:function(a,b){return b.length&&(a.timeout=b[0]),a}},A,B;B=function(a){function b(a){var a=a.split("!"),b=x.length,c=a.pop(),d=a.length,c={url:c,origUrl:c,prefixes:a},e,f,g;for(f=0;f<d;f++)g=a[f].split("="),(e=z[g.shift()])&&(c=e(c,g));for(f=0;f<b;f++)c=x[f](c);return c}function g(a,e,f,g,h){var i=b(a),j=i.autoCallback;i.url.split(".").pop().split("?").shift(),i.bypass||(e&&(e=d(e)?e:e[a]||e[g]||e[a.split("/").pop().split("?")[0]]),i.instead?i.instead(a,e,f,g,h):(y[i.url]?i.noexec=!0:y[i.url]=1,f.load(i.url,i.forceCSS||!i.forceJS&&"css"==i.url.split(".").pop().split("?").shift()?"c":c,i.noexec,i.attrs,i.timeout),(d(e)||d(j))&&f.load(function(){k(),e&&e(i.origUrl,h,g),j&&j(i.origUrl,h,g),y[i.url]=2})))}function h(a,b){function c(a,c){if(a){if(e(a))c||(j=function(){var a=[].slice.call(arguments);k.apply(this,a),l()}),g(a,j,b,0,h);else if(Object(a)===a)for(n in m=function(){var b=0,c;for(c in a)a.hasOwnProperty(c)&&b++;return b}(),a)a.hasOwnProperty(n)&&(!c&&!--m&&(d(j)?j=function(){var a=[].slice.call(arguments);k.apply(this,a),l()}:j[n]=function(a){return function(){var b=[].slice.call(arguments);a&&a.apply(this,b),l()}}(k[n])),g(a[n],j,b,n,h))}else!c&&l()}var h=!!a.test,i=a.load||a.both,j=a.callback||f,k=j,l=a.complete||f,m,n;c(h?a.yep:a.nope,!!i),i&&c(i)}var i,j,l=this.yepnope.loader;if(e(a))g(a,0,l,0);else if(w(a))for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)j=a[i],e(j)?g(j,0,l,0):w(j)?B(j):Object(j)===j&&h(j,l);else Object(a)===a&&h(a,l)},B.addPrefix=function(a,b){z[a]=b},B.addFilter=function(a){x.push(a)},B.errorTimeout=1e4,null==b.readyState&&b.addEventListener&&(b.readyState="loading",b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",A=function(){b.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",A,0),b.readyState="complete"},0)),a.yepnope=k(),a.yepnope.executeStack=h,a.yepnope.injectJs=function(a,c,d,e,i,j){var k=b.createElement("script"),l,o,e=e||B.errorTimeout;k.src=a;for(o in d)k.setAttribute(o,d[o]);c=j?h:c||f,k.onreadystatechange=k.onload=function(){!l&&g(k.readyState)&&(l=1,c(),k.onload=k.onreadystatechange=null)},m(function(){l||(l=1,c(1))},e),i?k.onload():n.parentNode.insertBefore(k,n)},a.yepnope.injectCss=function(a,c,d,e,g,i){var e=b.createElement("link"),j,c=i?h:c||f;e.href=a,e.rel="stylesheet",e.type="text/css";for(j in d)e.setAttribute(j,d[j]);g||(n.parentNode.insertBefore(e,n),m(c,0))}}(this,document),Modernizr.load=function(){yepnope.apply(window,[].slice.call(arguments,0))};


       </script> 


        <style type="text/css">

    /* */

    .grid {
    padding: 20px 20px 100px 20px;
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.grid li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 440px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
}

.grid figure {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.grid figure img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.grid figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #2c3f52;
    color: #ed4e6e;
}

.grid figcaption h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
}

.grid figcaption span:before {
    content: 'by ';
}

.grid figcaption a {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ed4e6e;
    color: #fff;
}



/* Caption Style 4 */
.cs-style-4 li {
    -webkit-perspective: 1700px;
    -moz-perspective: 1700px;
    perspective: 1700px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 0 50%;
    -moz-perspective-origin: 0 50%;
    perspective-origin: 0 50%;
}

.cs-style-4 figure {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.cs-style-4 figure > div {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cs-style-4 figure img {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s;
    transition: transform 0.4s;
}

.no-touch .cs-style-4 figure:hover img,
.cs-style-4 figure.cs-hover img {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(25%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(25%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(25%);
    transform: translateX(25%);
}

.cs-style-4 figcaption {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
    transform: rotateY(-90deg);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
}

.no-touch .cs-style-4 figure:hover figcaption,
.cs-style-4 figure.cs-hover figcaption {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
    transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
}

.cs-style-4 figcaption a {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 31.5em) {
    .grid {
        padding: 10px 10px 100px 10px;
    }
    .grid li {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 300px;
    }

}


*, *:after, *:before { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
body, html { font-size: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;}

/* Clearfix hack by Nicolas Gallagher: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: " "; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }



        </style>


    </head>
    <body>



        <div class="container demo-3">

            <ul class="grid cs-style-4">
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <div><img src="images/5.png" alt="img05"></div>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Safari</h3>
                            <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1116775-Safari">Take a look</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <div><img src="images/6.png" alt="img06"></div>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Game Center</h3>
                            <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1118904-Game-Center">Take a look</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <div><img src="images/2.png" alt="img02"></div>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Music</h3>
                            <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1115960-Music">Take a look</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <div><img src="images/4.png" alt="img04"></div>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Settings</h3>
                            <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1116685-Settings">Take a look</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <div><img src="images/1.png" alt="img01"></div>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Camera</h3>
                            <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1115632-Camera">Take a look</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <div><img src="images/3.png" alt="img03"></div>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Phone</h3>
                            <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1117308-Phone">Take a look</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div><!-- /container -->

        <script>
        /** Used Only For Touch Devices **/
( function( window ) {

    // for touch devices: add class cs-hover to the figures when touching the items
    if( Modernizr.touch ) {

        // classie.js https://github.com/desandro/classie/blob/master/classie.js
        // class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

        function classReg( className ) {
            return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
        }

        // classList support for class management
        // altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
        var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

        if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
            hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
                return elem.classList.contains( c );
            };
            addClass = function( elem, c ) {
                elem.classList.add( c );
            };
            removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
                elem.classList.remove( c );
            };
        }
        else {
            hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
                return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
            };
            addClass = function( elem, c ) {
                if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
                        elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
                }
            };
            removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
                elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
            };
        }

        function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
            var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
            fn( elem, c );
        }

        var classie = {
            // full names
            hasClass: hasClass,
            addClass: addClass,
            removeClass: removeClass,
            toggleClass: toggleClass,
            // short names
            has: hasClass,
            add: addClass,
            remove: removeClass,
            toggle: toggleClass
        };

        // transport
        if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
            // AMD
            define( classie );
        } else {
            // browser global
            window.classie = classie;
        }

        [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'ul.grid > li > figure' ) ).forEach( function( el, i ) {
            el.querySelector( 'figcaption > a' ).addEventListener( 'touchstart', function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            }, false );
            el.addEventListener( 'touchstart', function(e) {
                classie.toggle( this, 'cs-hover' );
            }, false );
        } );

    }

})( window );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

P.S: UPDATE For @Sharon: Please see the image
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqRCx.png)

Comment: your code is not clear. Can you just give the portion of the code which you want help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pretty_Girl

You have set width for li.. And obviously you cannot achieve the output you are expecting

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lpe00do/)

I have added a percentage width and not pixel width..

```
.grid li {width: 20%;}
```

Comment: Thank you @Sharon, but now, the image size is reduced, and four pictures doesn't fit to the full browser width (See the updated question with a image), how to increase the size of the image and set 4 images of the row to fit to full browser width without space?

Comment: And can you explain a little bit, why did you set the `.grid li {width: 20%;}` as there should be 4 images, so, for 4 images, isn't it to be set as 25% which is equal 4 parts of the full width?

Comment: Update: I set `.grid` to  `max-width: auto;` hoping that it would fit to the browser, but it increased it's size little bit, still it doesn't fit to the full browser width.

Comment: Yes you can set the width to 24%.. Cos your padding will let your columns go down.. Updated demo https://jsfiddle.net/3Lpe00do/1/

Comment: Thank you, if the padding is the case, suppose I don't need any padding, just, images stick to each other with no spaces, and fills the entire browser window width with 4 images.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to responsive layout also and arrange images in four set in group. then you can follow this link, i think this is best example of grid layout images.
[GRID LAY-OUT DEMO](http://alijafarian.com/responsive-image-grids-using-css/)